# Cognito form not displaying on WordPress page

Tags: cognito-forms

I made a custom form to insert on a page on my client's WordPress website. But, for some reason, the form does not show up, or if it does, it only shows up for me after I have refreshed the page a few times. In a different browser it doesn't show. I implemented the form by copying the HTML and pasting it in the text of the page.

Do you have any suggestions why the form isn't working?

The form is removed right now from the website because it does not work, but here it the script:

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/include/required"></script>
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/session/script/680d5cce-4f3b-4eb0-bbd5-3ec2ea5a70b3"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script>
</div>
```

The website I am placing the form on is: Asyoulikeitweddings.com

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/). When using Cognito Forms on a WordPress site you have two options:

1. You can download our [Cognito Froms Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cognito-forms/) through WordPress. You can then edit your form in WordPress and use the Cog icon to embed your form without having to use any code at all. When using this option some embed code will still be shown but you wont have to worry about copy and pasting it. Below is an example of how that code will look:

   `[CognitoForms id="1"]`
2. You can embed your form using the embed code that you provided. You will want to make sure you are adding the code to the code view of your content block, you can get to this view by clicking "Text" in the top right corner of the What You See Is What You Get editor(this is also know as a WYSIWYG editor). Once you have added your embed code to this view you can switch back to the normal WYSIWYG editor view by clicking "Visual".

If you need more support or any other help with WordPress plugin please [submit a support ticket](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) and we would be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, Thank you for your response. I actually already downloaded the plugin and inserted the embedded code from cognito onto the appropriate page's code view. Although, the form is still not showing up. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this? I have also opened a support ticket on the wordpress plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Just following up on Nicholas's response to add that the issue in this case was incompatibilities between Cognito Forms and a JavaScript library used on the website.  We are working through this as a support ticket, but this issue is with a specific theme, not WordPress integration itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. I added the code via the html text editor in a WP page. Using Chrome, the form showed up after refreshing several times. In Safari is showed up.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I work for a digital marketing company and have been experiencing these same issues at random with our client's sites. However, refreshing doesn't resolve the issue for us, the forms are just completely not appearing when embedded with the Cognito Forms seamless script. BUT when embedded with iFrame they do appear... not sure how helpful that is but figured I'd share!