# How to embed Cognito form into wordpress.com

Tags: cognito-forms, wordpress.com

I am trying to embed my form into my wordpress.com blog and it doesn't. Is there something wrong with my HTML?

```
<div class="cognito">
  <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/O8PupSKv1ka64YqUYmOy7g"></script>
  <script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cognito Forms does not currently support embedded on WordPress.com blogs. It looks like WordPress supports a specific embedding protocol that we plan on implementing support for over the next few weeks.  I have created a [feature card](https://trello.com/c/jLUf0eZf) that you can use to follow development and set up a notification when we release this feature.

Disclaimer: I am an engineer on the Cognito Forms team

Answer (score 0):

wordpress.com doesn't allow the use of `<script>` tags in your post's HTML.

To do that you'd need a self-hosted WordPress blog.

Comment: I used jotform before

Comment: And? Did that use a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Per [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70844/354) you need a plugin, but you can't add arbitrary plugins to wordpress.com.

Comment: Landed in the LQ queue.  Thought I would give you a chuckle ;)